# How to store a time interval (hour:minute:second) in Realm swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm currently creating a workout timer application.
I want to store *just* the hour:minute:second of the created timer object.

I first created a Time object:

```
class Time: Object {
    @objc dynamic var hour: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var minute: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var second: Int = 0
}
```

And I was using this object to represent the time interval. What I don't like about this approach is I get a separate Time table with hour, minute and second columns.

I then wanted to see if I could store a tuple (Int, Int, Int) to represent my time interval. But I received a warning that the tuple type cannot be represented in object-c. I also figured Realm probably wouldn't know what to do with a tuple.

So my question is. Whats the best way to store a user selected hour, minute and second time interval without also having to store an entire date object with the useless date attached to it.

I, of course, also need the ability to read that time interval from the backing store so that I can apply it to a timer.

EDIT:
I guess I could also just store it as a integer value of seconds and than parse that result in to hours, minutes, and seconds

Comment: What not a `Date`? It's lightweight enough as it's basically just a timestamp. Alternatively you could also just store a `TimeInterval` with is a fancy typealias for `Double`?

Comment: Definitely store it as a single unsigned Int, measuring seconds. That way, you can never run into inconsistencies where e.g. hour is 25 and minute is -1.

Comment: @YoamFarges If anything, for clarity. I think of a Date object as something to store a date, and not necessarily a time interval.

Comment: @Gereon yeah good call on the Uint. I think that'll be the best way to go.

Comment: `TimeInterval` is a builtin alias for `Double` for this reason. Why can't you use that?

Comment: @Connor For this to work I'd have to store a Double in the backing store. Unfortunately Realm doesn't recognize the TimeInterval type. At that point it kinda of seems like a 6 in 1 half dozen in the other situation between storing an Int representation of the time interval or a double.

Comment: Realm definitely does recognize Double (and therefore, it recognizes TimeInterval, as they are the same thing): https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#supported-types

Comment: @Connor that being said. Using TimeInterval instead would work, I would just have to change my interval parsing methods accept a TimeInterval instead of an Int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there are other prerequisites not described in the question, just use Swift's `TimeInterval` (typealias for `Double`, which is supported by Realm). I expect this is a property on some other modeled object (otherwise you're just storing arbitrary numbers) - let's say it's on a `Workout` object.

```
class Workout: Object {

    @objc dynamic var interval: TimeInterval = 0

}
```

If you want to pull out the hour/minute/second of the time interval, the quick and dirty solution is to `extension Double { }` with utility functions like `func inSeconds()`. But the better solution is to use [DateComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter), which can take your `TimeInterval` as input and spit those things out while handling far more edge cases for you.

Comment: I like the extension idea as I need to use a tuple consisting of hour:minute:second to then display in a picker view. Thanks

Comment: Yup. By all means, convert it to a tuple if you want to display that information, but Realm is your data storage - it shouldn't care about display-purposes things like that. It just needs the TimeInterval.

Comment: Yeah, the extension methods are for display purposes only.